# Link containing date variable is not working

Tags: php

here is a code snipet, I want to create the link to a website's image file using date function. That website has folders organized as : website/years/months/days but my code is not producing the link, it is just generating a number "2026" which is ambigious. 
It should like this output: 
http:/e.piyarawatan.com/paper/2017/04/05/p-1.jpg

```
<?php 
if($_GET['date']!=''){
   $date = $_GET['date']; 
 }
 else{
       $dateY = date('Y');
       $dateM = date('m');
       $dateD = date('d');
}
$linkString = "http:/e.piyarawatan.com/paper/" + $dateY + "/" + $dateM + "/" + $dateD + "/p-1.jpg";
//  echo "<img src=" + $linkString +"></img>";
echo $linkString;
?>
```

It is a little problem I am facing, I am actually creating a widget for my wordpress website that will fetch a picture from another website and show as a widget in sidebar.

Comment: PHP uses a `.` for string concatenation, and `+` for addition

Comment: what about that ? $linkString = "http:/e.piyarawatan.com/paper/".$dateY."/".$dateM."/".$dateD."/p-1.jpg";

Comment: All `$date_`  values are unset if the `GET` parameter is passed, or are those defined else where?